# Getting "column ambiguously defined" without any join in code

Tags: sql, oracle, union, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I get "column ambiguously defined" error while trying to execute following script:

```
INSERT INTO experience (id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_) 
WITH exp_ AS (
    SELECT 0, 0, DATE'2013-04-30', NULL, 11, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, DATE'2011-12-11', DATE'2013-04-30', 9, 'Administrator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 0, DATE'2013-04-30', DATE'2015-10-27', 6, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, DATE'2014-11-04', NULL, 10, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, DATE'2017-06-13', NULL, 13, 'CTO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, DATE'2010-04-22', DATE'2018-10-22', 1, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 1, DATE'2019-08-26', NULL, 2, 'Trainer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1, DATE'2006-02-27', DATE'2016-11-30', 6, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2, DATE'2012-04-30', DATE'2013-11-24', 5, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 2, DATE'2013-01-10', NULL, 0, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 2, DATE'2010-11-01', DATE'2017-01-01', 7, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 2, DATE'2010-10-03', DATE'2018-03-01', 8, 'Commentator' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM exp_;
```

I don't use any JOIN here, and the error description says, that it's caused by trying to join two tables with overlapping column's names.

So why I got it here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax would work only if you drop the `CTE` and directly insert the rows with `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO experience (id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_)
    SELECT 0, 0, DATE'2013-04-30', NULL, 11, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, DATE'2011-12-11', DATE'2013-04-30', 9, 'Administrator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 0, DATE'2013-04-30', DATE'2015-10-27', 6, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, DATE'2014-11-04', NULL, 10, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, DATE'2017-06-13', NULL, 13, 'CTO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, DATE'2010-04-22', DATE'2018-10-22', 1, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 1, DATE'2019-08-26', NULL, 2, 'Trainer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1, DATE'2006-02-27', DATE'2016-11-30', 6, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2, DATE'2012-04-30', DATE'2013-11-24', 5, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 2, DATE'2013-01-10', NULL, 0, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 2, DATE'2010-11-01', DATE'2017-01-01', 7, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 2, DATE'2010-10-03', DATE'2018-03-01', 8, 'Commentator' FROM DUAL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=994d0f23823d35931cb65b476527e0af).

Answer (score 1):

You need to give aliases to your columns. It is enough to do it in the first unioned subquery:

```
INSERT INTO experience (id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_) 
WITH exp_ AS (
    SELECT 
        0 id_, 
        0 company, 
        DATE'2013-04-30' start_, 
        NULL end_, 
        11 usr, 
        'CEO' position 
    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, DATE'2011-12-11', DATE'2013-04-30', 9, 'Administrator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 0, DATE'2013-04-30', DATE'2015-10-27', 6, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, DATE'2014-11-04', NULL, 10, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, DATE'2017-06-13', NULL, 13, 'CTO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, DATE'2010-04-22', DATE'2018-10-22', 1, 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 1, DATE'2019-08-26', NULL, 2, 'Trainer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1, DATE'2006-02-27', DATE'2016-11-30', 6, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2, DATE'2012-04-30', DATE'2013-11-24', 5, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 2, DATE'2013-01-10', NULL, 0, 'CEO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 2, DATE'2010-11-01', DATE'2017-01-01', 7, 'Video Creator' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 2, DATE'2010-10-03', DATE'2018-03-01', 8, 'Commentator' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM exp_;
```

For your use case, you could also consider using the `insert all` syntax, which avoids the multiple `union all`s:

```
insert all
into experience (id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_)
    values(0, 0, date '2013-04-30', null, 11, 'CEO')
into experience (id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_)
    values(1, 0, date '2011-12-11', date '2013-05-30', 9, 'Administrator')
...
select 1 from dual
```

Comment: Thanks, but I used exactly the same syntax before and had no problems with that. Why is this case special?

Answer (score 1):

You columns do not have names in the CTE.  Define it with names:

```
WITH exp_(id_, company, start_, end_, usr, position_) AS (
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ea8e2c7d5f27c7c86bb1cfcd07ef616a) is a db<>fiddle.